# Spring JPA Hibernate ddl-auto does not detects auto increment constraint change

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I created a simple SpringBoot application with a **User** entity as defined below:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

I found that adding `@GenerateValue` annotation does not adds auto_increment property to the primary key. Constraints for `id` from SQL workbench were `id: bigint PK`.

I later found that `auto_increment` can be added to the key by replacing `@GenerateValue` annotation with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`.

I made this change and re-ran the Spring Boot server and found that no change was made to the primary key i.e. auto_increment was not added. My ddl-auto property was `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

Then I updated the `ddl-auto` property to `create` which drops the table first and then creates a new table and found that the new table's primary key has the auto_increment property. The updated constraints in workbench were `id: bigint AI PK`.

Later, I also tried `validate` property of `ddl-auto` to see if hibernate could invalidate the schema constraints mismatch but it was unable to do so.

Can someone explain me the reason for this behaviour? Clearly `auto_increment` property not being set in the primary key must qualify for a schema mismatch and should be invalidated by `validate` and updated by `update` ddl-auto values.

Thank You.

Comment: A word of advice: don't use Hibernate's DDL generation for production. Use a DB migration tool

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate may have ignored the auto increment in validation because schema is something which represents your DB structure like Table, Column, Column types, size, table mapping etc. Auto increment comes in picture when there is an Insert into Table. It's just the way of generating one of the columns value not influencing structure.